# Where should I post my unfinished story I'm still writing?

Tags: fiction, publishing

I've written a few bad stories before, but I post them online anyway. All my past ones have been put on a [fanfiction](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/13032991/ceramicmrno0b) site, but the one I'm working on doesn't go there. It's still a work in progress, and I'm adding on regularly. I would like to keep it as 1 document the entire time I'm writing it so I don't have to run through my files to find a small detail. It's fiction, and I don't plan on making it a series. I would like a site where I can go back in the published version if I decide to add or remove details from a certain point. I looked into Inkitt, and it seems like a good option but I would like to find a site with a better writing format, and I didn't really like the general feel of the site. I'd like a site where my story could be reviewed, and have some communication method besides talking in the comments. That's one of the features I really liked about the fanfiction site, you could talk to other authors.

Sorry this question is kinda all over the place. Just looking for a site where-

- I can post my unfinished story
- and keep it in one document
- while still updating regularly, adding onto the story or going back to change something
- and getting advice/criticism from other authors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious candidate is [FictionPress](https://www.fictionpress.com/). It's run by the same people as FanFiction.net, and is essentially the same website with all the same features, the only different being that it's for original works. I have used it myself for several years and, while it's hit-or-miss as to whether anyone will comment on your stories (and whether their criticism is any good), it has all the other features you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I recently joined [Scribophile](https://www.scribophile.com) and have really found it valuable. Work posted there is private, so it's perfect for pre-publication, and they have a karma system which encourages people to post high-quality critiques.

They also have an active forum, and innumerable niche writer's groups. They have a paid upgrade tier, but the majority of the site's functionality is available at the free tier.